# Python's graph tool - computing ego net with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, graph-tool

I'm trying to compute ego-nets for 250k special nodes residing inside a relatively big network (8M nodes and 17M edges). Since the cutting process takes 3 seconds for each special node, I decided to use `multiprocessing`:

```
from graph_tool import Graph, GraphView
from graph_tool.topology import shortest_distance
from graph_tool import load_graph
import multiprocessing
import time

NO_PROC = 4
DEGREE = 4 # neighbours of n-th degree
NO_SPECIAL_NODES = 250000

graph = load_graph('./graph.graphml') #8M nodes, 17M edges

def ego_net(g, ego, n):
    print("Graph's identity: {}.".format(id(g))) # check if you use the same object as in other calls
    d = shortest_distance(g=g, source=ego, max_dist=n) #O(V+E)
    u = GraphView(g, vfilt=d.a < g.num_vertices()) #O(V)
    u = Graph(u, prune=True)
    return (ego, u)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # generate arguments
    data = [(graph, node, DEGREE) for node in range(0, NO_SPECIAL_NODES)]

    # choose forking strategy explicitly
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
    pool = ctx.Pool(NO_PROC)

    results = pool.starmap(ego_net, [piece for piece in data])
```

The problem with this approach is that, even though I explicitly choose `fork` [approach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), the `graph` object is not used by subprocesses but instead the big object is being copied into each of the subprocesses. This approach results in `MemoryError` since I can't provide enough RAM for copies of the `graph`.

I know there are [data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) defined in `multiprocessing` that support sharing between processes. They don't seem to support complex objects such as `Graph` that `graph` is an instance of. Is there any way to load the `graph` only once and let it be used by all the processes? I'm sure that `ego_net` function reads from the `graph` and doesn't modify object in any way.

Comment: I do not believe that what you want to do is strictly speaking possible. Part of the advantage of using a multiprocessing model is that you avoid GIL (global interpreter lock) contention. If you were to share complex Python objects between processes, they would have to share a GIL, which would defeat the purpose. I'll let someone more knowledgeable recommend a solution, however; I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to compute the shortest distance on a big network graph in parallel. You might be interested in GraphScope. This is the description:

> [GraphScope](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope) is a unified distributed graph computing platform that provides a one-stop environment for performing diverse graph operations on a cluster of computers through a user-friendly Python interface. GraphScope makes multi-staged processing of large-scale graph data on compute clusters simple by combining several important pieces of Alibaba technology: including GRAPE, GraphCompute, and Graph-Learn (GL) for analytics, interactive, and graph neural networks (GNN) computation, respectively.

Here is the quickly started of GraphScope:

```bash
# install graphscope by pip
pip3 install graphscope
```

```py
>>> import graphscope
>>> graphscope.set_option(show_log=True)
>>>
>>> # load graph
>>> from graphscope.dataset import load_p2p_network
>>> g = load_p2p_network()
>>>
>>> # run sssp algorithm
>>> pg = g.project(vertices={"host": ["id"]}, edges={"connect": ["dist"]})
>>> c = graphscope.sssp(pg, src=6)
```

Refer to [How to Run and Develop GraphScope Locally](https://blog.graphscope.io/how-to-run-and-develop-graphscope-locally-478beb7d509f) and [GraphScope Doc](https://graphscope.io/docs/latest/analytical_engine/builtin_algorithms#single-source-shortest-paths) for more information.